# Send a variable to a function and modify this variable in C

Tags: c, variables, pointers

I have the following vars:

```
char seed[NBITS + 1], x0[NBITS + 1], y0[NBITS + 1], z0[NBITS + 1], dT0[NBITS + 1];
```

And i want to change it values on this function:

```
void lfsr(char *bin, char *output)
{
    //bits significativos para fazer o xor NBITS -> NBITS,126,101,99;
    int bits[4];
    int bit;

    if(bin[0] == '0')
        bits[0] = 0;
    else if(bin[0] == '1')
        bits[0] = 1;

    if(bin[2] == '0')
        bits[1] = 0;
    else if(bin[2] == '1')
        bits[1] = 1;

    if(bin[21] == '0')
        bits[2] = 0;
    else if(bin[21] == '1')
        bits[2] = 1;

    if(bin[19] == '0')
        bits[3] = 0;
    else if(bin[19] == '1')
        bits[3] = 1;

    bit = bits[0] ^ bits[1] ^ bits[2] ^ bits[3] ^ 1;
    //reconstruir o vector de char depois do lfsr
    for(int i = 127; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        bin[i] = bin[i - 1];
    }

    bin[0] = (char)(48 + bit);  
    output = bin;
}
```

The way that I put the value in y0 from x is, for example, calling the lfsr functions like this:

```
lfsr(x0, y0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have to do 3 Fibonacci Linear Feedback Shift Register starting from x0.

```
x0 = 10101010101010
y0 = lfsr(101010101010)
z0 = lfsr(y0)
dT0 = lfsr(z0);
```

The results are good, but when I do the above code the value of x0 will be the same as dT0 if i use pointers.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks. Cumps!

Comment: This is begging for a loop.

Comment: What's the point of this, `output = bin;`?  Seems totally unnecessary.

Comment: thats the problem.. I don't know how to pass the bin value to variable y0.. I've tried with pointers, but then all variables that enter in that function will be the same..

Comment: If you pass the address of an array to a function, the function has direct access to the array and can modify its contents.  No need to pass it back.

Comment: Yes, but i need to do this to y0, z0 and dT0, and when I finish this the y0 value is the same as dT0 value.. and I want to avoid this situation

Comment: Pass the address as a constant array: `const char *`.

Comment: What's the purpose of your function?  What is some sample input and output?

Comment: Give me some sample input and output, in your question, so I can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: This function makes a Linear Feedback Shift Register from a binary number and saves it to another new one

Comment: Show code, and sample input, and the wrong output, and what do you expect from output, and what section you don't understand, finally the problem could be solve a lot faster.

Comment: @Fiddling Bits Yes, it's Fibonacci

Comment: Whatver the change is made, it is local to the function 'lfsr' and does not modify the actual array from the calling function(in c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

[image]

The numbers correspond to the taps.  The bits are actually 15..0, left to right.  The following is my implementation of the Fibonacci Linear Feedback Shift Register:

```
#include <stdio.h>

uint16_t fibLfsr(const uint16_t num)
{
    uint16_t tempNum;

    tempNum = (num) ^ (num >> 2) ^ (num >> 3) ^ (num >> 5);
    tempNum = (tempNum & 0x1) << 15;
    tempNum = (tempNum | (num >> 1));

    return tempNum;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t testNum = 0xACE1;

    printf("%#X\n", testNum);
    testNum = fibLfsr(testNum);
    printf("%#X\n", testNum);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not quite sure why you're using strings and converting them to binary.  If this is necessary, you'll need some of the standard library APIs in `stdlib` and `string` to convert the string to an `uint16_t` before calling `fibLfsr()` and back to a string afterwards.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I'm working with 128bit binary number.. So i need to work with char vector. Thank you very much. Cumps!

Comment: @arturataide If the taps are the same, converting `fibLfsr()` to accept and return a 128-bit number should be pretty straight forward.